# Spring Cloud Stream: Republish to other amqp connection if current connection throws exception

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I have 2 identical RabbitMQ servers, and I want to publish event to one of it (process exactly once), failing over to another in case of publishing failure.

- Spring Cloud Stream has 1 binder for each server.
- MQ servers have same exchanges and durable queues configured, but queues don't have HA policy.

The questions are:

1. What is the best design to do this? Preferably by making changes in high level Cloud Stream configuration, not diving into Spring AMQP.
2. How can I hook to asynchronous publishing and it's result? Preferably not by making it synchronous. Override some bean?
3. Can RabbitMQ HA help in any way? As I understood, the whole durable Queue is present only on single node to preserve order of messsages (actually I don't need the order). So if I configure HA and the node with durable HA queue fails/stops, processing and publishing will crash?

Comment: "What is the best design?" is not an answerable question... I think you need to narrow the focus of the question to one particular issue.

Comment: @theMayer I think there should be some sort of solid solution to that. All other questions here can become irrelevant if somebody offers a good design/architecture for that.

Comment: If you can describe your question in clearer terms, focusing on a specific issue, we could probably get it re-opened. Right now, it's just too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See the boot documentation:
   `spring.rabbitmq.addresses= # Comma-separated list of addresses to which the client should connect.` The connection factory will automatically fail over.
2. If you set the producer `errorChannelEnabled` you will get returned messages in the error channel; this needs a connection factory configured for returns. There is no current mechanism to get async positive acks, unless you use Spring AMQP directly to publish messages.
3. With HA, a new master node is selected for the queue(s) hosted by the failed node. While the queue is hosted on one node, it is copied to the others.